# Nextcloud bulk loading new data with Linux command line

Tags: linux, data, load, nextcloud

I have nearly 40,000 folders with over 187,000 files to add to a nextcloud server. I did quite a bit a research and finally find an answer which I give below. I added this here so others did not need to do the searching to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found an explanation on [help.nextcloud.com by fab](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/tutorial-how-to-migrate-mass-data-to-a-new-nextcloud-server/9418). Here is a summary of the steps to use.

- Working as root or using sudo.
- Find where the nextcloud data is stored. You typically will find this in the /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php. Search for datadirectory such as `grep datadirectory /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.ph/config.php`
- Determine which sub-directory you want to place the data you are loading and load the data to that directory.
- Change the ownership: `chown www-data:www-data -R /<directory you loaded to>/`
- `cd /var/www/nextcloud`
- Include the new directories and files into the nextcloud database with: `sudo -u www-data php console.php files:scan --all`

This may take some time. The 187,000 files on my system took 17 minutes to do the scan.